# Android N multi-locale support not working as intended

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

While developing an app, I tried use Android N multi-lingual support. As explained on developers [site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html). It seems that it will automatically pick the resources using resource resolution mechanism.

But it doesn't seem to be working or could it be that I am missing something?

**Here is the complete scenario :**

1. Device as Portugese(pt_PT) and German(de_DE) as preferred language list respectively.
2. Locales supported by app are placed in corresponding resource folder:

   a. values   (default)
   b. values-de
   c. values-es

So according to explanation provided on developers site it should pick locale from **"values-de"** directory. But it shows the default one.

**Could someone give me an idea of what might be going wrong??**

[image]

Comment: share a screenshot of your folder structure (showing all values folders) and the contents of strings.xml in each locale

Comment: I have added image for values folder structure, and contents are localized for each language.

Comment: folder structure looks ok. At the time you are expecting the app to pick another language have you changed the locale in phone settings? Or forced a locale using the code?

Comment: I am not changing the locale. From Android N, user can set a list of preferred languages based on which locale is used as explained on developer site (with a nice example) for "Android N Multi-lingual" support.

Comment: can you change the language on phone and see if it works. If it does there is something you are missing with implementing the N offerings

Comment: It is working if I change the first language in preferred language list to the one supported by the app. But if the first language in the preferred list is not the one supported by app then it's showing default locale.

Comment: so basically the fall back logic is not working. Compile and target sdk versions set to N?

Comment: Yes, both are set to API 24

Answer (score 5):

Ineteresting that this issue reproduces in sample project. But all works as intended if I remove "appcompat-v7" from compile dependencies. I don't know why for now and I'll keep digging.

UPDATE:

adding appcompact-v7 really fix the problem. watch this tutorial to understand why:

https://blog.egorand.me/a-curious-case-of-multiple-locales/

Comment: did you investigated why removing appcompact makes the change? I'm struggling with the same problem

Comment: Saved my life. added resConfigs "auto" into my "build.gradle" and works!

Comment: @LouisLam thank you! I just lost 2 days searching for bug! Also answer should be accpeted!

Comment: The link provided doesn't work anymore. Need to understand what goes wrong here. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue and found out that removing alternative resources the app does not need resolves the issue.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
      ...
      // Keeps language resources for only the locales specified below.
      resConfigs "de", "es"
    }
}
```

Check out Google Developer documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#unused-alt-resources)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add android:configChanges="locale" in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: android:configChanges="locale" attribute is already added in AndroidManifest.xml file. Is there something that I need to handle Acitvity class file??

Comment: You can handle it programmatically in activity class or just add in AndroidManifest.xml for activities 
       <activity        android:name=".HomeActivity"         android:configChanges="locale">

It worked for me very well.